# Remove blanks from beautifulsoup get_text

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm piecing together some stuff to try and get clean text from a website using beautifulsoup get_text.  In the past I have found it often comes back with some stuff that isn't what I needed so I've set about trying to make it as clean as possible.  My issue is, in what is returned I get some blank values.  My code is as follows:

```
def GetPageText():
    for page in GetTeamLinks():
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'} # some websites look for these sorts of headers to make sure you're not a bot
        response = requests.get(page, verify=False, headers=headers) ##go to each of the websites in the domain list
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser") # sets "soup" as their variable name
        for script in soup(["script", "style","a","nav", "footer"]): #find everything in the script or style tags
            script.extract()    # rip it out
        full_text = str(soup.get_text().splitlines()).strip() #set the variable 'full_text' as the text we get back
    return(full_text)
```

What's returned looks like this (this is an example from scraping https://www.nutmeg.com/about/executive-team )

```
['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'Executive team | Nutmeg - Nutmeg', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
'', '', '',
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '      
Executive team', '', '  ', '', '', '', 'The Nutmeg executive team', '', '', 
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'Martin Stead ', 'Chief executive officer', 
'', 'Martin joined Nutmeg in 2015. He has a range of experience running and 
jointly-running...........]
```

I'd like to get rid of the

```
 '', '', '', '',
```

values.

I have tried treating full_text as a list, and then go over that list and remove  all values less than 2 characters.  However, that doesn't seem to work in my for statement as it doesn't recognise full_text.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I have searched but have been unable to find an answer.  if there is something similar here, then please point me in the direction.

Many thanks

Rob

Comment: Have you tried like this `.get_text(" ",strip=True) `?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood your question.
You can get rid of the empty values with list comprehension:

```
my_list = ['', '', '', 'Executive team | Nutmeg - Nutmeg']

new_list = [i for i in my_list if i != '']

print(new_list)
```

I do not know what you want to do with the data afterwards, but it seems easier to try to specifically scrape data to know what you have.